# i cannot enter the http://localhost:8069/web/ odoo 16

Tags: odoo, pgadmin

[database access denied[internal server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxt4v.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuQG3.png)
i tried to create a data base on odoo 16 but it says that the access is denied to create it so i went to pgadmin to create one from there i created and i comback to open it on odoo but sadly this mesage appears : Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

i tried to create a data basr from pgadmin but it seems that it created some issues along the way

Answer (score 0):

The database is probably not initialized, you should see the following error message in the log:

```
Database %s not initialized, you can force it with `-i base`", cr.dbname
```

You can also set the `admin_passwd` in the config file and create a new database